# S3 Read csv file with wildcard inside zipped folder

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have csv file inside S3 in format as given below.

```
<bucket_name>/data.zip/data/part*.csv
```

I need to read this csv with wildcard (part*.csv) which there in zipped folder.

How can i do this using boto3 .  I am working on notebook of AWS sagemaker.

Thanks in advance.